# Run thread and ask about data during work

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a problem with my code. I'm running this code with `thread`, then I need to ask about variables SPEED, etc., but I don't know how. I'm still trying to do this, but I'm getting errors with `thread`.

BTW, I want to make a script that generates fake car data, and I need to fill a database, and then make some diagrams.

```
import time
import thread
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
    self.speed = 0
        self.dist = 0
        self.maxSpeed = 150
        self.time = 6
        self.fuel = 100
        self.distance = 100
        self.start = time.time()
        self.elapsed = 0

    def jazda(self):
        while True:
            self.speed += 1

            if self.speed < self.maxSpeed:
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                time.sleep(60)

            self.elapsed = time.time() - self.start
            self.dist = (self.speed * self.elapsed) / 3600

            print "Distance: ", self.dist
            print "Speed: ", self.speed
            print "Time: ", self.elapsed
            if self.elapsed > self.time:
                break
        return 0

    def SPEED(self):
        return self.speed
```

and second script:

```
import test
import thread
import time
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = test.Test()

    def get_speed(self):
        while True:
            return self.test.SPEED()
            time.sleep(2)

thread.start_new_thread( test.Test().jazda(), () )
thread.start_new_thread( obdData().get_speed, () )
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ```
> thread.start_new_thread( Test().jazda(), () )
> TypeError: first arg must be callable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the `thread.start_new_thread` method is expecting a method reference and not a method invocation i.e. `test.Test().jazda` is a method reference i.e. callable; however, `test.Test().jazda()` will return the result of the method (0 in this case) not a callable.  Your start method should look like `thread.start_new_thread(test.Test().jazda, ())`